# Setting up realms in Keycloak during kubernetes helm install

Tags: keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to get `keycloak` set up as a helm chart requirement to run some integration tests. I can get it to bring it up and run it, but I can't figure out how to set up the realm and client I need. I've switched over to the 1.0.0 stable release that came out today:

https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/keycloak

I wanted to use the `keycloak.preStartScript` defined in the chart and use the `/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh` admin script to do this, but apparently by "pre start" they mean before the server is brought up, so `kcadm.sh` can't authenticate. If I leave out the `keycloak.preStartScript` I can shell into the keycloak container and run the `kcadm.sh` scripts I want to use after it's up and running, but they fail as part of the pre start script.

Here's my `requirements.yaml` for my chart:

```
dependencies:
- name: keycloak
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
  version: 1.0.0
```

Here's my `values.yaml` file for my chart:

```
keycloak:
  keycloak:
    persistence:
      dbVendor: H2
      deployPostgres: false
    username: 'admin'
    password: 'test'
    preStartScript: |
      /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password 'test'
      /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=foo -s enabled=true -o
      CID=$(/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create clients -r foo -s clientId=foo -s 'redirectUris=["http://localhost:8080/*"]' -i)
      /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get clients/$CID/installation/providers/keycloak-oidc-keycloak-json
  persistence:
    dbVendor: H2
    deployPostgres: false
```

Also a side annoyance is that I need to define the persistence settings in both places or it either fails or brings up `postgresql` in addition to `keycloak`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this too and also hit this problem so have [raised an issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/5917). I prefer to use -Dimport with a realm .json file but your points suggest a postStartScript option would make sense so I've included both in the PR on that issue

Answer (score 1):

Enable `keycloakconfigcli` in the helm values file and, under the Configuration section, add the `realm`, `client`, and other details as JSON. Then there is no need for running the post- or pre-start scripts.

Example JSON:

```json
configuration:
    realm1.json: |
      {
        "realm": "",
        "enabled": "true",
        "registrationAllowed": false,
        "roles": {
            "realm": [
              {  
                "name": "",
                "composite": false,
                "clientRole": false
              },
              {
                "name": "",
                "composite": false,
                "clientRole": false
              }
          ]
        },
        "users": [
            {
              "username": "",
              "email": "",
              "enabled": true,
              "firstName": "",
              "lastName": "",
              "realmRoles": [
                ""
              ],
              "credentials": [
                {
                  "type": "password",
                  "value": ""
                }
              ]
            }
        ],
          {
            "clientId": "",
            "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true,
            "redirectUris": [""],
            "webOrigins": [""],
            "bearerOnly": false,
            "rootUrl": "http://ip or domain",
            "adminUrl": "http://ip or domain"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: This is solution works well however the json syntax configuration is incorrect in the example you provided as it is missing an opening [ for the client config. You are missing the line ‘“clients”: [‘ before { “clientId”